# Law of total expectance for a sum

Tags: probability

The law of total expectane is $E(X) = E_Y(E_{X|Y}(X|Y))$, but how does one expand this for a sum $\mathrm{E}(\sum X_i)$ ?

> \begin{align}A)&&
> \mathrm{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right)=\mathrm{E}\left(\mathrm{E}\left(\left.\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right|X_1,\ldots, X_N\right)\right)
> \end{align}

or

> \begin{align}B)&&
> \mathrm{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right)=\mathrm{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\mathrm{E}\left(\left. X_i\right|X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\ldots,X_N\right)\right)
> \end{align}

or simply

> \begin{align}C)&&
> \mathrm{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right)=\mathrm{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\mathrm{E}\left(\left. X_i\right|X_1,\ldots,X_N\right)\right)
> \end{align}

?

It should be relatively straightforward, but I just want to be sure. If it's relevant, $X_i$ are all independently chosen from the same distribution.

Comment: Clarrify: Is $N$ a constant or another random variable?

Comment: @GrahamKemp $N$ is indeed a constant!

Comment: @FrankVel where did you get this notation? $E_{X|Y}(X|Y)$

Comment: @MANMAID I got it from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148829/understanding-law-of-total-expectation), and it looks useful, because the $\mathrm{E}$xpectancy-functions are different.

Comment: well, write $E_Y(E_{X\mid Y}(X))$ or $EE(X\mid Y)$, etc... I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, sure, they are all valid, if not particularly useful.   Just consider the case $N=3$.

$$\mathsf E(X_1+X_2+X_3) ~{= \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_1+X_2+X_3\mid X_1,X_2,X_3))\\ =\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_2,X_3)+\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1,X_3)+\mathsf E(X_3\mid X_1,X_2)) \\ =  \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_1\mid X_1,X_2,X_3)+\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1,X_2,X_3)+\mathsf E(X_3\mid X_1,X_2,X_3)) } $$

---

When $N$ is itself a random variable, what might be more useful is:

$$\mathsf E(\sum_{k=1}^N X_k) = \mathsf E(\sum_{k=1}^N\mathsf E(X_k\mid N))$$

Particularly when each $X_k$ is an identical and independently distributed random variable (and independent of $N$ as well), this simplifies to:

$$\mathsf E(\sum_{k=1}^N X_k) = \mathsf E(N)\mathsf E(X_1)$$